# How to create a text component where first word of sentence to be bold?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a text component where first word of the sentence to be bold. Right now with my solution, when a user enter "Tips: favourite vacation", I get " **Tips:** favouritevacation", where rest of sentence becomes mess and no space is created after Tips:. This isn't elegant solution. I thought about creating another component like TextBold and use it like this < Text >< TextBold >Tips:< /TextBold > Your Vacation< /Text >, but this seems unnecessary. Is there a way to get this working within Text component alone? https://codesandbox.io/s/text-component-v2dbt?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface TextProps {
  children?: string;
}

export const Text: React.FunctionComponent<TextProps> = ({
  children
}: TextProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{children?.split(" ")[0]}</span>
      <span>{children?.split(" ").slice(1)}</span>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Text>Tips: favourite vacation</Text>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of first space char index and `.substring`

```
export const Text: React.FunctionComponent<TextProps> = ({
  children = ""
}: TextProps) => {
  const firstSpaceIndex = children.indexOf(" ");
  return (
    <>
      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        {children.substring(0, firstSpaceIndex)}
      </span>
      <span>{children.substring(firstSpaceIndex)}</span>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit text-component (forked)]

Comment: This works, thanks! Just wondering let's say consumer of this component does not want any space between Tips: and favourite so they type in "Tips:favourite vacation".  With a little tweak to your solution, can this case be handled?

Comment: @JudoboyAlex in this case, you could do some kind of `children.replace(":", ": ")` prior to finding the first index of space char

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{children?.shift()}</span>
<span>{children?.split("").slice(1)}</span>
```

Comment: I had to use children.split("").shift(), but this gets first letter only to become bold.

Comment: You're right.
try using :
`
      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{children?.split(" ")[0]}</span>
      <span>{children?.split(" ").slice(1).join(' ')}</span>
`

Comment: Tips became bold but there is no space after so look like this Tips:favourite vacation.

Comment: try using : ``` <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{children?.split(" ")[0].push(" ")}</span> <span>{children?.split(" ").slice(1).join(' ')}</span> ```